# Sorting prices from 3 product line item types using views

Tags: commerce, views

My goal is to display a message like "Prices start from 13.34$" for every taxonomy term that I created. I have 3 product types with 3 product line item types. What I did until now and I'm stuck is to create a view with the contextual filter "Content: Has taxonomy term ID", after I added the "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" relationship, without this, the contextual filter wasn't there (if I remember correctly) and I also added the "Content: Product Referance" relationship and here is my problem because when I add the referance from one of my product line item types everything is fine, I just added the price field and sort it by amount, but when I add the other 2 relationships for the products on the other line item types nothing is displayed, but if I uncheck the "require this relationship" for everything, the smallest prices from all 3 product line items is displayed.

Using this view I add it as a field to another view (using Views field module) and other fields that I require and everything works like a charm.

I was thinking to exclude them from display and using some sort of PHP sorting to display the smallest value from them, but I don't know how to do that.

Maybe there is another module or another much simpler solution to this, thanks for your time and suggestions.